What causes intense red flares in the sky around midnight?
Last night (2024-10-12 01:09 thru 01:11 CEST) I made a couple of pictures of the starry sky and found some strange flares right above the horizon. See the picture fragments below. All pictures have an exposure time of 15", f/4, ISO 2500, and 28 mm focus:



The star triangle right below the flares seems to be comprised of 23 CVn, 20 CVn, 19 CVn, and 13 CVn (the star at the bottom). Annotated versions of the original photos are found here:

very long and bright red flare
shorter, less bright flare
very short flare

Location: 53.135299/8.336343
Viewing direction: north.
What causes these flares in the middle of the night? I can already exclude Iridium satellites, as they have polar trajectories.
UPDATE: I've also seen the flares without camera, so they are "real".

The images are so small (low resolution) and focus so blurry it's hard to tell much of anything about them.

Speculation, so posting this as a comment and not an answer: Could this be a very weak aurora borealis? (inb4: at this time of year, in this part of the country...)

The green illumination maybe yes, but the flares I'm askin' 'bout…?

I posted a comment earlier, then deleted it because I didn't want to seem disagreeable, but I'm reposting now... I fail to see what this has to do with photography. It might be an interesting question, but it doesn't belong here as far as I can tell. Just because you can photograph something, doesn't make identification of the object a photography question. If you were asking how to capture such events/objects, that would be a photography question - but this question is really no different to photographing a bird or aircraft and wanting to identify it.

Who said that my question is not related to astrophotography?

You are simply trying to identify something you photographed in the sky. That's not a (astro)photography question. As I said, if you were asking how to capture something, that would be a valid question. There's absolutely nothing about photography in your question - you just want to know what you've seen.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about photography.

Well they're not the Orionids, wrong part of the sky.  If they were cosmic ray tracks on your sensor (just about plausible) or lens flare (not likely) that would be on topic, so having seen them with the naked eye isn't helpful!

Pure assumption: military aircraft. Possibly full afterburner.
Apparently, NATO is holding "Steadfast Noon", an alliance nuclear deterrence exercise, that started October 14, lasting for two weeks.

This year’s exercise involves flights mainly over host countries Belgium and the Netherlands and in airspace over Denmark, the United Kingdom and the North Sea. Planning for the exercise began a year ago and thirteen Allies will send aircraft to take part in the drills.

Your photos were taken a couple days before the official start of the exercises. But that doesn't mean aircraft weren't practicing, or ferrying or staging a couple days ahead of the operation.

The first one looks like a very low resolution plane - because of the red on one side.
The second and third images look like small meteors, typical shape.
As an example, I'm attaching a cropped image showing a small meteor during the aurora back in may 2024.


If you don't see the flare with your own eyes as a line, but it's seen as a line by the camera, then it's something that's moving way faster than stars due to rotation of Erath and long exposure makes it appear as a line.
Several possibilities:

Satellites, but just some different satellites than Iridium or other polar trajectory satellites
Aeroplanes. They move and have lights that can make these flares.
Meteors, although meteors move quite fast so the line in 15 second exposure would probably be longer than it's now.

Yesterday in search of the comet, I saw some star-like objects that were nevertheless moving. I suspect satellites, but I can't exclude aeroplanes. If they were meteors, they probably would have been moving faster.

I can exclude airplanes because they have blinking lights additionally to the (red and green) continuous ones, and I've also photographed meteors, but they were not nearly as bright as the flared and produced much longer lines.

Satellites are rather unlikely.  The low orbit ones are eclipsed around midnight, though quite visible at dawn and dusk.  The high orbit ones don't move very fast and are not very bright.  I would bet on airplanes.  I don't think they use the flashing lights away from the airport but am not sure.

Yes, most satellites are hardly visible in the middle of the night. If this had been an aircraft, wouldn't the trail have been longer and with more than one bulge because of the strobe lights?

The length of meteor path must vary quite a lot and depends on it's vaporization time in the atmosphere and how far it is away. Also the bottom part of trace will be darker because of reduction in vaporization and OP's examples have that.

The length of airplane trails can vary greatly depending on the angle the flight makes with the camera and the distance from the camera to the airplane.  Note the first and third are on almost parallel courses

@RossMillikan Airplanes typically run the strobes the entire time they are in the air. Tactical or strategic military flights may not, but all civilian aircraft are supposed to.

Regarding airplanes: sometimes you just don't see the lights blinking, depending on your position relative to the plane. In the 2nd picture it looks like the is some blinking, though, and the frequency matches some of my own pictures of planes.

@user24582 I've never caught aircraft at night that the blinking strobes weren't obvious. Landing/takeoff lights (the bright spotlights pointed ahead) are turned off shortly before takeoff and only turned back on shortly before landing. The strobes are much brighter than the green and red position lights. Those are the only external lights when they're cruising at altitude.

@Neppomuk The exception to the midnight rule of thumb is when they are low near the poles and arctic circles. The observer can be on the ground on the dark side of the terminator, but even at midnight the terminator can still be just a few miles to the north. It's not like at or near the equator, where at midnight the terminator is 6,000+ miles and 90° of arc away.

@Michael C Yes, usually you see the blinking.

@RossMillikan Near the arctic circles lower satellites to the north (or even "over the pole") can still be seen reflecting sunlight around midnight because the further north you go the fewer degrees of arc it is from a location at noon to a location at midnight at the same latitude, and the sun never dips very far below (or very far above) the horizon near the solstices.

Equinoxes, not solstices. At the solstice the sun remains in the sky at midnight above the arctic circle. We're currently only about three weeks past the autumnal equinox in the northern hemisphere.
